# How to whitelist a directory that was previously blacklisted in pylsp

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp

I think I accidentally blacklisted a directory. More specifically

```
myproject
├── test.py
├── folder1
├── folder2
└── ...
```

I had that and opened `test.py` then pylsp gave me the option to create/import a new project. I selected no, but then it blacklisted the whole directory `/home/user/Documents/myproject`. How to whitelist that whole directory again? I'd image this is possible, but I've been searching and haven't found the command/key shortcut to do that.

Inside `folder1,folder2`, etc I have more files but now when I open them I get the message that they are blacklisted too.

Comment: Can you try `lsp-workspace-blacklist-remove`?

Comment: Yes, that works. I was about to post that solution myself.